# Assign a value to the protected string

Tags: symbols

How can I assign a value for a symbol composed of a string plus and another string converted from integer?

```
n=3;
Symbol["as"<>ToString[n]]=4;
```

So I want to assign a value 4 to the new symbol as3. But it does not work.

Comment: `Evaluate@Symbol["as" <> ToString[n]] = 4`. It will only work once.

Comment: Linked topic should answer your question, let me know if you disagree with closing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
n = 3;
Set[#, 4]& @ Symbol["as" <> ToString[n]]
```